# Bash- How to pack escape character into a special character ($) inside a string?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a variable in  bash return from a function call getpassword() which return "apple$123123"

```
FOO=`getpassword`
```

I would like to use FOO variable which contains $ inside and pass into expect program

```
 expect -c "\
    set timeout 90
    set env(TERM)
    spawn rdesktop 192.168.11.1
    expect \"Password:\"
    send -- \"'${FOO}\n'\"
    interact
  "
}
```

There is an error coming out as $FOO contain dollar-sign

```
Password: can't read "123": no such variable
    while executing
```

How can i solve this kind of problem? The way i think is that to pack escape character into FOO, using sed?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a variable, or a variable containing that string, or a file containing that string, or…?

Comment: You know executing `FOO="apple$123$"` will store the string `apple23$` into `FOO` because it will try to interpret `$1`, right? Did you mean `FOO='apple$123$'`?

Comment: If it's a variable, it’ll already have interpolated `$1`. There’s no way to reverse that.

Comment: Oh...i have changed the question a bit. see if know how to solve.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
# below is purposely on one line -- it sets the FOO env var
# only for the duration of the expect command.
FOO=$(getpassword) expect -c '
    set timeout 90
    set env(TERM) {are you missing something here?}
    spawn rdesktop 192.168.11.1
    expect "Password:"
    send -- "$env(FOO)\r"    # you send '\r' not '\n'
    interact
'
```

Using single quotes make it easier to write (and read) the expect script (without all the backslashes). Testing:

```
$ getpassword() { echo 'abc$123'; }
$ FOO=$(getpassword) expect -c 'puts "pw=$env(FOO)"'
pw=abc$123
$ echo "> $FOO <"
>  <
```